# Change mysql date / time / datetime default output format

Tags: mysql, laravel, datetime, timestamp

Is it possible for mysql to change the default date, time, datetime, timestamp etc. format?

At this moment return 2015-12-31

I want to always show 2015.12.31 Without additional formatting.

Is this possible?

p.s.

Maybe laravel can set the default date and time representation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **accessors** to change the value you get from the model and **mutators** to change the way a value is stored in the database.

You can use classic [Date/Time](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) function such as `date` to manipulate the dates, or use the [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) library, which extends the PHP [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.datetime.php) class, and offers an easy and intuitive way of manipulating dates and times (Carbon comes bundled with Laravel so there's no need to install anything).

```
class Foo extends Model 
{
...
    public function getMydateAttribute() {
        return date('Y.m.d', strtotime($this->attributes['mydate']));        
    }

    public function setMydateAttribute($value) {              
        $this->attributes['mydate'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value);
    }
...
}
```

You can read more about accessors and mutators in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators).